# What word refers to a code segment/function that can be/is executed concurrently/in parallel by two different threads?

Tags: multithreading

I came across this term while studying threads, synchronization, and writing multi-threaded programs. If I remember correctly, it refers to a section of code that two threads execute in parallel.

If I remember incorrectly, it might actually refer to a section of code that can run *simultaneously*. Then again, I might be off entirely (sorry).

The term is on the tip of my tongue and I (desperately) want to google it.

Comment: Critical zone? Shared code? Anyways, it's off-topic here. Take a look at the Help Center.

Comment: It's synonymous with 'shared code'. I'm not sure *where* to ask if not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RENTRANT** and **THREAD-SAFE**.  Both are necessary.

See [this Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) on "reentrant":

> In computing, a computer program or subroutine is called reentrant if
>   it can be interrupted in the middle of its execution and then safely
>   called again ("re-entered") before its previous invocations complete
>   execution. The interruption could be caused by an internal action such
>   as a jump or call, or by an external action such as a hardware
>   interrupt or signal. Once the reentered invocation completes, the
>   previous invocations will resume correct execution.
>
> This definition originates from single-threaded programming
>   environments where the flow of control could be interrupted by a
>   hardware interrupt and transferred to an interrupt service routine
>   (ISR). Any subroutine used by the ISR that could potentially have been
>   executing when the interrupt was triggered should be reentrant. Often,
>   subroutines accessible via the operating system kernel are not
>   reentrant. Hence, interrupt service routines are limited in the
>   actions they can perform; for instance, they are usually restricted
>   from accessing the file system and sometimes even from allocating
>   memory.
>
> A subroutine that is directly or indirectly recursive should be
>   reentrant. This policy is partially enforced by structured programming
>   languages.[citation needed] However a subroutine can fail to be
>   reentrant if it relies on a global variable to remain unchanged but
>   that variable is modified when the subroutine is recursively invoked.
>
> This definition of reentrancy differs from that of thread-safety in
>   multi-threaded environments. A reentrant subroutine can achieve
>   thread-safety,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) but being reentrant alone might not be sufficient to
>   be thread-safe in all situations. Conversely, thread-safe code does
>   not necessarily have to be reentrant (see below for examples).
>
> ...

Comment: Rentrant! Aha! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is a [Critical Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) - a piece of code whose function is critically important when dealing with multiple threads.

However, your question posits a block of code that can run simultaneously on multiple threads, which is different than a critical section - a critical section is specifically a block of code that must run on only one thread at a time, for instance, incrementing a bank balance. It's the type of code where one would expect that multiple threads could try to run it, but specifically requires that only one thread actually be allowed to run it at one time.

There is no name, to the best of my knowledge, for a block of code that could be executed simultaneously on multiple threads, because lots of code does that innocuously.